# How to filter an array with the help of another array on JS view using vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, vuex, store

Using VueX, I try to filter my "ListJobs" array based on currentTag. Basically I'm trying to say that if currentTag contains any of the elements that match the rows role, level, languages and tool then it returns the elements that match.

```
   state: [
      listJobs: [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "company": "Photosnap",
        "role": "Frontend",
        "level": "Senior",
        "languages": ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"],
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "company": "Manage",
        "role": "Frontend",
        "level": "Senior",
        "languages": ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"],
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "company": "Account",
        "role": "Frontend",
        "level": "Senior",
        "languages": ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"],
      },
    ],
    currentTag: [],
```

I tried something like this. It works but only for the Role line. I wish it would work for all my lines

```
  getters: {
    getJobs(state) {
      if (state.currentTag.length > 0) {
        return state.listJobs.filter(job => job['role'].includes(state.currentTag))

      } else {
        return state.listJobs
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Its actually easier with `.some`

```
  getters: {
    getJobs(state) {
        return state.listJobs.filter(job => state.currentTag.some(tag => tag === job.role))
    }
  },
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it gives me this error in the devtool view: 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Frontend is not a function